# How can you test that a function is invoking another function?

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart, mockito

I'm new to unit testing, especially in Dart/Mockito, so maybe I'm approaching this all wrong. I have an authentication system that has a `registerPreLogoutCallback(PreLogoutCallback callback)` method, which adds the given asynchronous callback to a list. When `logOut` is called, I use `Future.wait` to wait until each of these callbacks has executed, then actually log the user out.

When testing the `logOut` method, I'd like to make sure that any registered callbacks have been called. Therefore, I figured I should call `registerPreLogoutCallback` a few times in the unit test, and somehow verify that the registered callbacks have been called. Is this possible? Does it violate the purpose of a unit test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If part of `logOut`'s definition is that it calls the `PreLogoutCallback`, then that is part of `logOut`'s unit test. It's fine to use `registerPreLogoutCallback` as part of the test, but you're not testing `registerPreLogoutCallback`. Instead, `registerPreLogoutCallback` gets its own unit test.

`logOut`'s unit test would include something like this vaguely Javascript shaped pseudo-code.

```
// Set the callback to be a closure around `preLogoutCalled`.
// registerPreLogoutCalled() has its own unit test, we know it works.
var preLogoutCalled = false
registerPreLogoutCallback( function() { preLogoutCalled = true } )

// Logout
logOut()

// Check the callback was called
assert(preLogoutCalled)
```

If `logOut` is responsible for passing arguments to the callback, you might put tests in the callback itself to check the callback got the right arguments. Let's say the callback gets the current user.

```
logged_in_user = ...

registerPreLogoutCallback(
    function(user) { assertEq(user, logged_in_user) }
)

logOut()
```

The best part is it's entirely [black-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing). Calling the callbacks is part of `logOut`'s defined behavior. No assumptions need to be made about how `logOut()` is implemented.

Comment: The Javascripty example is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your detailed response!